# How can I create a loop in R that searchers a data frame for files containing certain values, and subsetting them?

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, subset

Let's say I have this data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Setting = c("start", "continue focal", "end", "start", "continue focal", "end", "start", "continue focal", "end", "start", "continue focal", "end"),
  Behaviour = c("grooming", "sleep", "fight", "grooming", "sleep", "fight", "grooming", "sleep", "fight", "grooming", "sleep", "fight")
)
```

At first glance, I see here 4 subsets of rows (beginning with start, and finishin with end). What can I do to extract these 4 subsets so I have them separetely as data frames?

I have tried creating a while loop, so it searchers row by row if there appears certain values (start and end) and then everything between them (including them), are converted into a new data frame. Although, I find myself really stuck as I cannot get this working.

Comment: In your example, do you mean that there are 4 subsets of rows? I see start/end 4 times.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Now edited.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, here's one possible solution.

1. Create an indicator for whenever a new sequence starts
2. Calculate the cumulative sum for the indicator variable
3. Use `split` to cut the data frame based on the variable with the cumulative sum

```
data <- data.frame( Setting = c("start", "continue focal", "end", "start", "continue focal", "end", "start", "continue focal", "end", "start", "continue focal", "end"),
                    Behaviour = c("grooming", "sleep", "fight", "grooming", "sleep", "fight", "grooming", "sleep", "fight", "grooming", "sleep", "fight") )

dataGrouped<-data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(newStart = ifelse(Setting=="start",1,0)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cumulativeSum = cumsum(newStart))
  
split(dataGrouped,dataGrouped$cumulativeSum)
```

Comment: Yes, what I want to do is to obtain a set of files, using the criteria for each set the column Setting (files where start is included + files where end is included = one subset. In this case, there would be 4 subsets of rows

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, please try the below code

steps:

1. derive var2 which has the serial number
2. create a vector with the serial numbers
3. map2 to derive 4 dfs

```r
data <- data.frame(
  Setting = c("start", "continue focal", "end", "start", "continue focal", "end", "start", "continue focal", "end", "start", "continue focal", "end"),
  Behaviour = c("grooming", "sleep", "fight", "grooming", "sleep", "fight", "grooming", "sleep", "fight", "grooming", "sleep", "fight")
) %>% mutate(var1=ifelse(Setting=='start', rleid(Setting),NA)) %>% fill(var1) %>% 
  mutate(var2=rleid(var1))

vars <- levels(factor(data$var2))

map2('data',vars, \(x,y) {
  x1 <- get(x)
  x2 <- x1[x1$var2==y,]
  assign(paste0('df',y),x2, envir = globalenv())
}
)


[[1]]
         Setting Behaviour var1 var2
1          start  grooming    1    1
2 continue focal     sleep    1    1
3            end     fight    1    1

[[2]]
         Setting Behaviour var1 var2
4          start  grooming    4    2
5 continue focal     sleep    4    2
6            end     fight    4    2

[[3]]
         Setting Behaviour var1 var2
7          start  grooming    7    3
8 continue focal     sleep    7    3
9            end     fight    7    3

[[4]]
          Setting Behaviour var1 var2
10          start  grooming   10    4
11 continue focal     sleep   10    4
12            end     fight   10    4
```